# spark scala convert a nested dataframe to nested dataset

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a nested dataframe "`inputFlowRecordsAgg`" which have follwoing schema

```
root
 |-- FlowI.key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FlowS.minFlowTime: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FlowS.maxFlowTime: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FlowS.flowStartedCount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- FlowI.DestPort: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FlowI.SrcIP: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bytes: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- FlowI.DestIP: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bytes: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- FlowI.L4Protocol: byte (nullable = true)
 |-- FlowI.Direction: byte (nullable = true)
 |-- FlowI.Status: byte (nullable = true)
 |-- FlowI.Mac: string (nullable = true)
```

Wanted to convert into nested dataset of following case classes

```
case class InputFlowV1(val FlowI: FlowI,
                             val FlowS: FlowS)

case class FlowI(val Mac: String,
                 val SrcIP: IPAddress,
                 val DestIP: IPAddress,
                 val DestPort: Int,
                 val L4Protocol: Byte,
                 val Direction: Byte,
                 val Status: Byte,
                 var key: String = "")

case class FlowS(var minFlowTime: Long,
                          var maxFlowTime: Long,
                          var flowStartedCount: Long)
```

> but when I try converting it using
>   inputFlowRecordsAgg.as[InputFlowV1]

```
cannot resolve '`FlowI`' given input columns: [FlowI.DestIP,FlowI.Direction, FlowI.key, FlowS.maxFlowTime, FlowI.SrcIP, FlowS.flowStartedCount, FlowI.L4Protocol, FlowI.Mac, FlowI.DestPort, FlowS.minFlowTime, FlowI.Status];
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`FlowI`' given input columns: [FlowI.DestIP,FlowI.Direction, FlowI.key, FlowS.maxFlowTime, FlowI.SrcIP, FlowS.flowStartedCount, FlowI.L4Protocol, FlowI.Mac, FlowI.DestPort, FlowS.minFlowTime, FlowI.Status];
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
```

One comment asked me for a full code, here it is

```
def getReducedFlowR(inputFlowRecords: Dataset[InputFlowV1],
                            @transient spark: SparkSession): Dataset[InputFlowV1]={


     val inputFlowRecordsAgg = inputFlowRecords.groupBy(column("FlowI.key") as "FlowI.key")
      .agg(min("FlowS.minFlowTime") as "FlowS.minFlowTime" , max("FlowS.maxFlowTime") as "FlowS.maxFlowTime",
        sum("FlowS.flowStartedCount") as "FlowS.flowStartedCount" 
        , first("FlowI.Mac") as "FlowI.Mac"
        , first("FlowI.SrcIP") as "FlowI.SrcIP" , first("FlowI.DestIP") as "FlowI.DestIP"
        ,first("FlowI.DestPort") as "FlowI.DestPort"
        , first("FlowI.L4Protocol") as "FlowI.L4Protocol"
        , first("FlowI.Direction") as "FlowI.Direction" , first("FlowI.Status") as "FlowI.Status")

        inputFlowRecordsAgg.printSchema()

        return inputFlowRecordsAgg.as[InputFlowV1]

        }
```

Comment: Is it possible to post your full code ? or post sample data related to your schema ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, try adding select statement to your code & let me know if its not working .. & also remove all your "FlowI." & "FlowS.".

Comment: is there any reason not to use map and compose a new InputFlowV1 within it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is your case class schema has not matched with actual data schema, Please check the case class schema below. try to match your case class schema to data schema it will work.

Your case class schema is :

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- FlowI: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Mac: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SrcIP: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- DestIP: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- DestPort: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- L4Protocol: byte (nullable = false)
 |    |-- Direction: byte (nullable = false)
 |    |-- Status: byte (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FlowS: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- minFlowTime: long (nullable = false)
 |    |-- maxFlowTime: long (nullable = false)
 |    |-- flowStartedCount: long (nullable = false)
```

Try to change your code like below it should work now.

```
val inputFlowRecordsAgg = inputFlowRecords.groupBy(column("FlowI.key") as "key")
      .agg(min("FlowS.minFlowTime") as "minFlowTime" , max("FlowS.maxFlowTime") as "maxFlowTime",
        sum("FlowS.flowStartedCount") as "flowStartedCount" 
        , first("FlowI.Mac") as "Mac"
        , first("FlowI.SrcIP") as "SrcIP" , first("DestIP") as "DestIP"
        ,first("FlowI.DestPort") as "DestPort"
        , first("FlowI.L4Protocol") as "L4Protocol"
        , first("FlowI.Direction") as "Direction" , first("FlowI.Status") as "Status")
        .select(struct($"key",$"Mac",$"SrcIP",$"DestIP",$"DestPort",$"L4Protocol",$"Direction",$"Status").as("FlowI"),struct($"flowStartedCount",$"minFlowTime",$"maxFlowTime").as("FlowS")) // add this line & change based on your columns .. i have added roughly..:)
```

Comment: thanks @Srinivas, its working. Though I expected some other mechanism other than using select and struct. I felt that it will have some extra performance implication as compared to using a direct coversion from dataframe to Dataset(thats why I was using "FlowI.*" and "FlowS.*")